# Find which resources are filtered

Tags: android, eclipse, filter, resources, drawable

[image]

From the image above in a working android project. I would like a way to get the filters so I can compare them to something else I'm working on. For example I'd like to have an array that contains "mcc311,mnc490","mcc311,870".....,"mcc312,mnc530" etc. So I'm looking for a way to get the filters that the project actually uses.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this and it was pretty simple.  In values-mcc310-mnc120 for example, i would put in a xml file defining a variable signifying what mcc and mnc identification im using.

For example, in values-mcc311-mnc870 i would have a xml file called networkcode.xml with contents of:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="network_id">MCC311/MNC870</string>
</resources>
```

this way i can read in that value of network_id at run time and know for certain what filter android is using.